# Getting the range of a data frame including zero

Tags: r

Here is a simple question. I have a data frame with values ranging from 0 to 3 and I want to get the number of elements of the dataset, which should be 4 in this case. Here is an example of the data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), X2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L), X3 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), X4 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), X5 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L), X6 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I've tried `diff(range(d))` but it doesn't count 0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the confusion is that `diff` gives the difference of the endpoints (in your example, the range is 0 to 3, the difference of which is 3; if the range was 1 to 4, the difference would still be 3. The 0 is a red herring). What you want is the number of integers within the range 0 to 3 which is (assuming that the endpoints are integers) one more than the difference. `diff(range(d))+1` (as @Tom said in another comment). Again, this would be true if the numbers were 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Yeah, except the OP just mentioned that `length(unique())` returns 136 for them, which suggests that they do not in fact have data that consists of only the values 0,1 2 and 3.

Comment: @joran True, I wasn't keeping up with all the comments. We need to see structure of `d` to know.

Comment: Well, I think `diff(range(d))+1` solves the problem. I was just wondering if R had a more elegant way to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It appears that the piece of information you left out is that you wanted the unique values in a data frame. R considers that a list, whose length is the number of columns. So `length(unique(unlist(dat)))` is what you should be doing, I think.

Comment: joran, you're absolutely right, that's what I had been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length(unique(...))` does some possibly unexpected (although thoroughly documented) things when applied to a matrix or data frame.

```
s <- structure(list(X1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L), X2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L), X3 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), X4 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), X5 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L), X6 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

When applied to a data frame, `unique` returns the unique rows in the data frame.  `length()` then counts the number of *columns* in the data frame.  So in general (I can't think of a counterexample), this will always be equal to `ncol(s)`.

```
length(unique(s))  ## 6
```

`unique` applied to a matrix also returns the unique rows, but now `length()` counts the total number of elements: for your data this will usually be equivalent to `ncol(s)*nrow(s)`.

```
length(unique(as.matrix(s)))  ## 54
```

If you want to apply `unique` to the elements in this situation, you probably want one of the following, all of which collapse the original data frame down to a single vector:

```
length(unique(as.vector(as.matrix(s)))) ## 4
length(unique(unlist(s)))  ## 4
length(unique(c(as.matrix(s)))) ## 4
```

Whether you want `diff(range(x))+1` or `length(unique(...))` depends on how you would want to count a data frame composed (for example) entirely of `{0,1,2,4}` -- should that return 4 or 5? (As @Brian Diggs points out in his answer, `diff(range(...))+1` will work on a matrix, without needing to flatten the structure further -- it will also work on an `unlist()`ed data frame.)

Answer (score 3):

`diff(range(d))` returns the difference between minimum and maximum, being 0 and 3 respectively

What you want to do is count how many elements there are in a set. Try `length(d)`

```
d <- 0:3
length(d)
```

Including the comments to this answer... Let the code speak

Example data:

```
dataset = 1:136
dataset = dataset %% 4
dim(dataset) <- c(4,34) //Now we have a table
diff(range(dataset))+1
```

It returns 4 like you wanted

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried length, but that's not exactly what I need. I have a dataset with 136 elements, each element ranging from 0 to 3. I need to get the number of possible answers (from 0 to 3, including 0 as an answer). :)

Comment: So you want the number of values that appear in the dataset, right? Let's assume it has 5 elements instead of 136. You want it to return 1 for 33333 or 11111 ... 2 for 22233, 21111 or 03030 .... 3 for 12322 .... 4 for 01230 ... Is it something like this? Then as joran said, length(unique(d)) will do the trick

Comment: No, no. It's much simpler than that. Consider the sequence

    {0 2 1
    2 3 1
    3 2 2
    1 0 3} -- I want to get the range of values including 0 as a value. Thus it should be 4.

Comment: @Werner then I'm totally in the woods as to what you meant. If it sill isn't the thing, could you update your question and post the actual R commands to create a dataset like yours and give us examples of desired input and output?

Comment: @Werner `length(unique())` does what you describe. If it doesn't, then you haven't successfully described what you need to do.

Comment: Alright, I'll try something else. For some reason length(unique()) is returning "136" instead of 4. Maybe that's happening because my data are in a matrix?

Comment: @Werner If that's the case then you have rather massively misled us about the structure of your data. Edit your question to include a reproducible example that illustrates your data.

Answer (score 3):

Given the structure of `d` you have now provided, you can do a column-by-column calculation of this.

```
> diff(range(d$X1))+1
[1] 3
> diff(range(d$X1))+1
[1] 3
> diff(range(d$X2))+1
[1] 4
> diff(range(d$X3))+1
[1] 4
> diff(range(d$X4))+1
[1] 3
> diff(range(d$X5))+1
[1] 3
> diff(range(d$X6))+1
[1] 2
```

Or you can loop over all the columns

```
> lapply(d, function(dp) {diff(range(dp))+1})
$X1
[1] 3

$X2
[1] 4

$X3
[1] 4

$X4
[1] 3

$X5
[1] 3

$X6
[1] 2
```

Or if you want the range for all the columns collectively, treat it as a matrix:

```
> diff(range(as.matrix(d)))+1
[1] 4
```